# How to compress an image using PIL

Tags: python, save, python-imaging-library, tiff, image-compression

I would like to compress and image using PIL, but when I execute it the image is still the same size. How do I solve it?

What I tried so far?

```
img.save('Compressed_image.tiff', dpi=[300,300], quality=35)
```

I tried to change the quality but the file size is always the same.

Comment: I think you need to specify the type of compression — i.e. `compression="tiff_lzw"`. See [Saving Tiff Images](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/handbook/image-file-formats.html#saving-tiff-images) in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

define the new width and height of the image

then use the following to downscale, before saving

```
img = img.resize( (width, height), Image.LANCZOS)
```

also, since TIFF is a lossless format, reducing the quality parameter would not have any effect on the saved filesize.

Comment: I don't think the OP wants to change the dimensions of the image — and instead just wants to reduce the overall **file size** by compressing the image data.

Comment: Yes, I would like to reduce the overall file size and not the dimensions of the image